# How to open Multiple webpage one after another in python?

Tags: python-2.7, loops, web

Let us consider the following example:

```
import webbrowser
Cn=('Acharya Girish Chandra Bose College','AJC Bose College','Ananda Mohan College','Asutosh College','Bangabasi College','Barrackpore Rastraguru Surendranath College','Basanti Devi College')

Cnw={'Acharya Girish Chandra Bose College':'http://www.agcbosecollege.org/','AJC Bose College':'http://www.ajcbosecollege.org/','Ananda Mohan College':'http://anandamohancollege.ac.in/','Asutosh College':'http://www.asutoshcollege.in/','Bangabasi College':'http://bangabasi.org/home.php','Barrackpore Rastraguru Surendranath College':'http://www.brsnc.org/','Basanti Devi College':'http://www.basantidevicollege.edu.in/'}

yy=['Y','Yes','YES','y']
nn=['N','NO','no','No','n']
i=0
while i<=range(len(Cn)):
    print 'College Name : ',Cn[i]
    a=raw_input('Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :')
    if a in yy:
        webbrowser.open(Cnw[Cn[i]])
    elif a in nn:
        break
    i=i+1
```

This program works fine, but I want to open next website after opening a webpage. This program open only one website and then opening another, but it skips one website every time. Here :
[Image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmRXK.png)

After opening one website from list it will increase i by i=i+1 and again ask to me to open the next website. Please suggest to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure as to why you're using `range()`, simply using `len(Cn)` is enough, however you should change it to `i<len(Cn)` so you don't go over the index on the last iteration of the while loop.

Additionally, when you `break` out in your `elif` statement, you end the loop. I'm unsure if this is what you're trying to do, if you would rather keep parsing through the list simply remove the `elif` statement. You also would not need your `nn` list of no variations.

```
import webbrowser
Cn=('Acharya Girish Chandra Bose College','AJC Bose College','Ananda Mohan College','Asutosh College','Bangabasi College','Barrackpore Rastraguru Surendranath College','Basanti Devi College')

Cnw={'Acharya Girish Chandra Bose College':'http://www.agcbosecollege.org/','AJC Bose College':'http://www.ajcbosecollege.org/','Ananda Mohan College':'http://anandamohancollege.ac.in/','Asutosh College':'http://www.asutoshcollege.in/','Bangabasi College':'http://bangabasi.org/home.php','Barrackpore Rastraguru Surendranath College':'http://www.brsnc.org/','Basanti Devi College':'http://www.basantidevicollege.edu.in/'}

yy=['Y','Yes','YES','y']
nn=['N','NO','no','No','n']
i=0
while i<len(Cn):
    print 'College Name : ',Cn[i]
    a=raw_input('Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :')
    if a in yy:
        webbrowser.open(Cnw[Cn[i]])
    #elif a in nn:
    #   break
    i=i+1
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
College Name :  Acharya Girish Chandra Bose College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :n
College Name :  AJC Bose College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :n
College Name :  Ananda Mohan College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :n
College Name :  Asutosh College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :n
College Name :  Bangabasi College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :n
College Name :  Barrackpore Rastraguru Surendranath College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :n
College Name :  Basanti Devi College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :n
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
College Name :  Acharya Girish Chandra Bose College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :y
College Name :  AJC Bose College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :y
College Name :  Ananda Mohan College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :y
College Name :  Asutosh College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :y
College Name :  Bangabasi College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :y
College Name :  Barrackpore Rastraguru Surendranath College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :y
College Name :  Basanti Devi College
Do u want to visit the website ? (Y/N) :y
>>>
```